# In java Programming this basic use

Tags: java

I am new to Java Programming.

I want to understand the basic difference between the code below

```
this.customerPage.selectcustomerrecent(Customer);

this.customerPage  = this.customerPage.selectcustomerrecent(Customer);
```

Comment: The difference really depends on what `selectcustomerrecent(...)` does. We can't tell you if we don't know anything about your `CustomerPage` class.

Comment: CustomerPage class contains function that are using in another class to call this function we uses this.customerPage.selectcustomerrecent(Customer);  selectcustomerrecent() is the method in the another class which has one parameter

Comment: Just to make that very clear: SO is **not** programming school teaching **the very basics**.

Answer (score 4):

```
this.customerPage.selectcustomerrecent(Customer);
```

This piece of code means that **customerPage** is an instance variable and it has a method named **selectcustomerrecent** which takes argument of Class type **Customer**

```
this.customerPage  = this.customerPage.selectcustomerrecent(Customer);
```

This is same as above and the only difference is that the response value of method **selectcustomerrecent** is reassigned to the instance variable **customerPage**.